# Geom Polygon cutting my GGMAP in Quarters

Tags: r, ggmap

When running my code, my map gets cut by an X.  I can't post the data, but I can post the code.  I am trying to use Voronoi diagrams on a ggmap and layer in points on top of that.  The map is looking good, but half is a voronoi and half is the map.

```
sbbox <- make_bbox(lon = c( -98.70445,-98.31298), lat = c(29.35194,29.6695))
sq_map <- get_map(location = sbbox, maptype = "terrain", source = "google")

ggmap(sq_map)  + 
  geom_polygon(fill = 'grey') +
  geom_segment(data = deldir_ds,
               aes(x = y1, y = x1, xend = y2, yend = x2), 
               size = .50, linetype = 2, color = rgb(229/255, 229/255, 229/255)) +
  geom_point(data=newstores, 
             aes(x = newstores$LON_L, y = newstores$LAT_L)) +
  geom_point(data=newsa45, 
             aes(x = newsa45$LON_K, y = newsa45$LAT_K, colour = "red")) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image: Current Map]

Comment: What's the purpose of the second line in your `ggmap()` call (i.e. `geom_polygon(fill = 'grey') +`)? That appears to be responsible for the two gray triangles.

Comment: When I don't have that in there, I don't get the greyed out Voronoi part, just the map

Comment: Try setting a different colour to your Voronoi. It appears to be a very pale grey right now, which is indistinguishable from the white road lines on the map. You shouldn't need the grey polygon to show the Voronoi.